# RDLC file generating PDF and send via email

Tags: asp.net, email, pdf-generation, rdlc

I'm generating PDF files from RDLC report programaticaly without a viewer (ASP.NET 2.0 C#).

I would like to find a way to send it directly via email without downloading the PDF file. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest these two approaches.. See which one fits best for you

http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2006/03/02/How-to-render-client-report-definition-files-_28002E00_rdlc_2900_-directly-to-the-Response-stream-without-preview.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/reporting-services/PDFUsingSQLRepServices.aspx

Comment: the problem it´s not just rendering the report, but sending automatically as a email... thanks any way

Answer (score 1):

I think Jonathon has posted exactly what you need in this answer to my (similar) question a few days ago:

[Distributing RDLC output as an email attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849276/distributing-rdlc-output-as-an-email-attachment/3849290#3849290)

Comment: thanks for the link, i had seen that before, but the solution fits well to winforms applications, my problem is doing it from asp.net...